# Unable to programmatically dismiss/disable instant markup screenshot presented in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

Below code i was applying in ios 10, this was working perfectly. But when ios 11 came, it's automatically save all screenshots in, not allow to dismiss instant markup screenshot.

```
for (int k = 0; k<[imgAry count]; k++) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgBaseView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [imgBaseView drawViewHierarchyInRect:imgBaseView.boundsafterScreenUpdates:YES];
    [imgBaseView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image.CGImage, (__bridge 
    CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
}
```

Comment: what is imgBaseView ? is it `UIImageView` ?

Comment: No,  imgBaseView is UIView. and in imgBaseView added another three UIImageView with transparent images